# how can I set multiple Values in one Variable type int java

Tags: java, eclipse, class, android-studio

how i can set a values 10,11,12,13,14 in variable NO_OF_QUESTIONS_PER_LEVEL in class Constant.java without Error in Class FragmentPlay.java

> class Constant.java

```
public class Constant {
    public static int NO_OF_QUESTIONS_PER_LEVEL  = 10,11,12,13,14 ; //I need use 10,11,12,13,14 not 10 only
}
```

> class FragmentPlay.java

```
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        if (quextionIndex >= Constant.NO_OF_QUESTIONS_PER_LEVEL - 1) {
            levelCompleted();

        } else {
            quextionIndex++;
            //wrongeQuestion();
            mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateUITimerTask, 100);
        }

    }
}
```

note i use Android Studio

Comment: I suggest you to learn java before creating android apps. Have a look at the [Java Collections Framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use array, list or set to store multiple values in a variable in java

Comment: Please give me example